# Finding aerodynamic coefficients of an airfoil using numerical data measured in wind tunnel

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, drag, aerodynamics, aircraft

I am trying to find all the aerodynamic coefficients of an airfoil at different angles of attack. I have .DAT files for data which have 4 columns of data all in order {angle of attack[deg], Lift[N], drag[N], momentum[N]}. The equations I am using for calculating aerodynamic coefficients are given as:

$$
\frac{2p}{\rho sv^2}
$$

where, $p$ = force in any direction(Lift, drag, momentum), $s$ is an area and the
free stream dynamic pressure in wind tunnel in given by $\rho v^2/2$ =100 kg/m$^2$.

What should I use as the reference area $s$ for calculations? I know that the purpose of $s$ is for the nondimensionalization of the equation. I used the square of the chord. I also need to calculate how does the centre of pressure change as the angle of attack changes.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: S should be the surface area of the projection of the wing when seen from above. The center of pressure location depends on [airfoil camber](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/50326/what-factors-are-included-in-the-moment-coefficient-of-a-wing/50380#50380).

Comment: So the formula should be like : chord x length of airfoil

Comment: No. Chord = length of airfoil. S = b x c, with b = width and c = chord.

Comment: hey thanks for taking your time to answer my question. I solved the lab exercise.